# How to add between two deltatime in python

Tags: datetime, python-2.7

I have two string deltatime. I'm going to add two deltatime. There is unsupported operand "+" in Python. Is there any idea ?

```
delA = "00:45:34.563"

delB = "00:25:24.266"

a = datetime.datetime.strptime(delA, "%H:%M:%S.%f")

b = datetime.datetime.strptime(delB, "%H:%M:%S.%f")

print a, b
1900-01-01 00:45:34.563000 1900-01-01 00:25:24.266000

print a-b
0:20:10.297000

print a+b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-31453f7268bc> in <module>()
----> 1 print a+b

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: And what is the result you are expecting for?

Comment: Expecting : "01:10:58.829"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `timedelta` to a `datetime`. Maybe you could do something like this:

```py
>>> b_timedelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=b.hour, minutes=b.minute, seconds=b.second,  microseconds=b.microsecond)
>>> result = a + b_timedelta
>>> print result
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 10, 58, 829000)
>>> print result.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
'01:10:58.829000'
```